# Use $this->property as a variable in a class method getter

Tags: php, class, methods, this

It wasn't easy to describe my problem in the question title, so I hope my showcase will make things clear.
I want to rewrite my php class code so it's more OOP based. Here's the current setup (this code actually works):

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    function beforeFilter() {
        $table = 'news';
        $var = $this->$table->getNewsArticles();
    }
}
```

This is the new setup I want to pursue:

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    private $table = null;
    
    function beforeFilter() {
        $this->table = 'news';
        $var = $this->$this->table->getNewsArticles();
    }
}
```

It's very clear that it's not possible to write '$this->$this->table' because an error is thrown. Should I keep using my first setup? Or how do you guys get this done?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't use `$this->news->getNewsArticles()`?

Comment: For the duplicate I marked, the accepted answer won't help you but there's a different answer on that question using curly brace syntax that is what you're looking for.

Comment: @rickdenhaan, thanks a lot! Your provided link did the trick! :D
And oh, the 'news' must be a variable in my case. In fact, my method could be $this->news->getNews() or $this->tag->getTags() or $this->products->getProducts() ...